# how to use jtable plugin in cakephp and ajax

Tags: php, cakephp, url-rewriting, routes, jquery-jtable

I am working on cakephp project where I am using Jtable A JQuery plugin to create AJAX based CRUD tables. I am accessing data from :

```
 localhost/mydomain/ControllName/functionName i.e

 localhost/mydomain/My/getUserPlan
```

I have given action in the following way but is taking same page url as a action

Here is my code:

```
$('.list-of-location').jtable({
    title: 'Table of location',
    actions: {
        getUserPlanAction:'/My/getUserPlan'   // It is not used by Jtable, instad taking same page url 
    },
    fields: {
        arrivaldate:{
            title: 'From',
            width: '40%'
        },
        departuredate: {
            title: 'To',
            width: '40%',
            key: true,
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: false
        },
        country: {
            title: 'Destination',
            width: '40%'
        },
        regular_cost:{
            title: 'reguler budget',
            width: '20%'
        },
        backpacker_cost: {
            title: 'low budget',
            width: '30%',
            type: 'date',
            create: false,
            edit: false
        }
    }
});   

$('.list-of-location').jtable('load');
```

any idea how do I give the action.
I also tried :

1) getUserPlanAction:'getUserPlan'

2) getUserPlan:'/My/getUserPlan'

3) getUserPlan:'getUserPlan'

4) action:'/My/getUserPlan'

as a action but none of these working & getting error:

```
 An error occured while communicating to the server.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got it working just by using :

```
listAction:'/domain/My/getUserPlan'
```

as a action